# PCIe slots and SLI enabled on mobo

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I'm building a workstation with a GTX 1080 Ti on a MSI x470 mobo.
The main difference between the GAMING PRO CARBON and the GAMING PRO, is the SLI support which is on only for the first one.
I'm planning to add in the future a second GTX 1080 Ti, I guess I have to take the carbon right?
I was just wondering what is the sense of producing mobos without SLI support, having more than one PCIe express X16 slots? Probably I'm not an expert, but must be another usage. I mean, if I have a mobo without SLI and I put on two Nvidia graphic card, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have two graphics cards, yes, the SLI-compatible [MSI x470 GAMING PRO CARBON](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/X470-GAMING-PRO-CARBON/Specification) version is required.

There are other uses for PCIe x16 cards, such as [NVMe M.2 -> PCIe drive adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0714MMD6M) [more](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0753JTJTG) on a card. Therefore, there are justifications to build a motherboard, such as the [MSI x470 GAMING PRO](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/X470-GAMING-PRO/Specification), without SLI support but with two x16 slots.

Sometimes, there's a second 16-bit slot, but [not all the pins are populated](https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-pci-express/4/), so it's really an x8 or x4 slot. The aforementioned motherboard drops from x16 to x8 if there are two 16-bit cards installed. So does the [MSI x470 GAMING PRO CARBON](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/X470-GAMING-PRO-CARBON/Specification) because there are only so many data lanes available from any given CPU.